# Detect if link opened in new tab or window or direct url access

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone know how to achieve this.

I have an index.php that loads a file page.php into a div using jQuery. This page.php has a link that when you click it loads page2.php into the same div(so the url always stays as index.php).

I want to make it so that, if you open the link on page.php in a new tab or window, instead of loading page2.php, it loads index.php(with page.php in the div). Same if you type in the link to page2.php directly into the browser.

Comment: Not possible unless you specify that any link with a target set to blank goes to 'index.php'.

Comment: You could change the links in `page.php` to point to `index.php?page=page2` and rewrite them in your jQuery AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Use a session.

On page 1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['beenhere'] = 1;
```

on page 2

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['beenhere'])){
    header('./index.php');
}
//rest of page....
```

Comment: I tried adding page 1 code to my index.php and page 2 code to my page2.php. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is for the 'open in new tab' part

**index.php**

```
<a href="index.php" onclick="javascript:$('#myDiv').load('page2.php');return false;">Link</a>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

To make it work also if the user writes the direct link to the page just check in page2 if it has a referer and if doesn't just send him to index.php

**page2.php**

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!="index.php"){
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/index.php");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

set a global variable on index.php and if it isn't there when page.php is loaded, redirect to index.php.

Comment: sorry matthew, i'm just starting to learn php. Could you give me some example code?

Comment: -1 - global variables don't persist over multiple page views unless they are persisted in the session or some other storage